# Can a Jew give a Gentile a tattoo?

Tags: halacha, tattoo

The [Rambam says](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.12.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that the issur of getting a tattoo is primarily on the person giving the tattoo and not the receiver. Putting aside that it isn't clear that getting a tattoo is asur from the text (later poskim take this up), it also isn't clear if the issur is giving a tattoo in general or specifically giving a tattoo to a fellow Jew. If I am a Jewish tattoo artist and I am working on a Gentile client, am I violating the issur?

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47701&st=&pgnum=88&hilite=

Answer (score 1):

The Minchas Chinuch(253) brings from the Mishnas Chachamim who held that to corner off the hair of a non jew is prohibited would also prohibit a Jew to give a non Jew a tatto. However,the achronim have paskened that it is permitted since a nonjew is not included in the passuk whatsoever.

Rav Chaim Kanievsky(פתשגן הכתב 89,& 93) is puzzled by this and uses the phrase tzarich iyun gadol on this idea that a Jew would be prohibited from giving a non jew a tatto. See Nodah Beyudah Kama EH Siman 135 who holds it is permitted.

Noda Beyehuda:

אבל באמת לא מיירי כלל באיסור ובקרא כתיב וכתובת קעקע לא תתנו בכם ובישראל הזהיר אבל מותר אפי' לישראל לקעקע בבשר הכותי כשם שמותר להקיף פאת כותי ואמנם עבד שמל וטבל הרי הוא כישראל לדבר זה כיון שחייב במצות